# Estimate total balls based on the ball count in a bin

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, balls-in-bins

I am struggling to formalise the following problem. We randomly spread $m$ balls into $n$ bins. $m$ is unknown, but $n$ is known in advance. Now, we sample the first bin (or any bin) and see it has $k$ balls. Can we say something about $E[m]$ in that case? Can we know how $m$ is distributed?

Comment: You could do this using Bayesian methods if you had a prior distribution for $m$.  The likelihood is ${m \choose k}\frac{(m-1)^{n-k}}{m^n} \mathbf I_{[m \ge k]}$.

Comment: For $~m \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$ let $~f(m)~$ denote the probability that there are exactly $~m~$ balls, given that there were exactly $~k~$ balls in the first bin.  Then, the computation is $$\frac{\sum_{m = 1}^\infty \left[ ~m \times f(m) ~\right]}{\sum_{m = 1}^\infty f(m)}.$$  Note that the denominator above *normalizes* $~f(m).~$  So, the problem reduces to computing $~f(m), ~$ then (if feasible) obtaining a closed form expression for the denominator above, and then (if feasible) obtaining a closed form expression for the numerator above.

Comment: Re last comment, a minor alternative is to let $~\displaystyle W = \sum_{m=1}^\infty f(m),~$ and try to obtain a closed form expression for $$\sum_{m=1}^\infty \left[ ~m \times \frac{f(m)}{W} ~\right].$$

Comment: You might be interested in the [Mark and recapture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_and_recapture) method.